# abnormal behaviour while displaying char array in C++ after object initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, pointers

main():

```
char inp[] = "(A+B)/(C*D))";

Infix i;
cout << "In main: " << inp  /* + ')' */  << endl << endl;
```

Here is `Infix` constructor:

```
Infix() {
        push('(');
        cout << "Element In Stack: " << *returnElement(returnTop()) << endl;
        outputString = "";
        strcpy(operatorArray, "/*-+%");
        cout << "Operator Array: " << operatorArray << endl;

    }
```

Infix is inheriting from a class 'Stack':

```
class Stack{
int top = -1;
char arr[100];

public:
    bool push(char);
    char pop();
    char peek();
    bool isEmpty();
    void displayAll();
    char returnTop() { return top;}
    char* returnElement(int i) {
        if(i > 98){
            cout << "StackOutOfIndex";
            return nullptr;
        }
        return &arr[i];
    }
```

};

When I run the code in main, it displays unusual output:

```
Element In Stack: (
Operator Array: /*-+%
In main: +%


Stack Object Destroyed!
```

But, when in main, if the comment the line declaring 'Infix' object declaration, the code runs fine:

```
In main: (A+B)/(C*D))
```

**EDITS:**

> Stack Class

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
    int top = -1;
    char arr[100];

    public:
        bool push(char);
        char pop();
        char peek();
        bool isEmpty();
        void displayAll();
        char returnTop() { return top;}
        char* returnElement(int i) {
            if(i > 98){
                cout << "StackOutOfIndex";
                return nullptr;
            }
            return &arr[i];
        }

};

bool Stack:: push(char elementToPush) {
    if(top > 98) {
        cout << "\nStack Overflow!!";
        return false;
    } else {
        arr[++top] = elementToPush;
        return true;
    }
}

char Stack:: pop() {
    if(top <= -1) {
        cout << "\nStack Underflow!!";
        return ' ';
    } else {
        return (arr[top--]);
    }
}

char Stack:: peek() {
    if(top > 98) {
        cout << "\nStack Overflow!!";
        return ' ';
    } else {
        return arr[top];
    }
}

bool Stack:: isEmpty() {
    return (top <= 0);
}

void Stack:: displayAll() {
    if(top <= -1) {
        cout << "null";
        return;
    }
    int i = top;
    while (i >= 0) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        --i;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

> Infix Class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<D:\Programs\11Stack.cpp>

using namespace std;

class Infix : public Stack {
    string outputString;
    char operatorArray[];
    public:
        Infix() {
            push('(');
            cout << "Element In Stack: " << *returnElement(returnTop()) << endl;
            outputString = "";
            strcpy(operatorArray, "/*-+%");
            cout << "Operator Array: " << operatorArray << endl;

        }

        string infixToPostfix(char *, int);
        bool manupulateOperator(char, int); 
        int checkPrecedence(char);

        ~Infix() {
            cout << "\nStack Object Destroyed!" << endl;
        }
};

string Infix:: infixToPostfix(char *str, int size) {
    cout << "\nGiven String: " << str << endl;
    int x;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++size) {
        x = str[i];
        if(x != ' ') {
            if(x == ')') {
                while(returnTop() != '(') {
                    cout << pop() << " popped!\n";
                }

                    cout << pop() << " popped!\n";
            } else if(isalpha(x)) {
                cout << x;
        } /* else{ // scanned character is an operator
            if(manupulateOperator(x, i)) {

            } else {
                return " ";
                }
            } */
        }
    }

    return outputString;
}

bool Infix::manupulateOperator(char c, int position) {
    try {
        char topElement = *returnElement(returnTop());
        if(checkPrecedence(c) == -1) {
            cout << "\nErr\n";
        }else if((checkPrecedence(c) > checkPrecedence(topElement)) || returnTop() == 0) {
            push(c);
            cout << c << " pushed!\n";
        }
    } catch(std::exception e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return false;
    } catch (char* Ce) {
        cout << Ce << endl;
    }

    return true;
}

int Infix::checkPrecedence(char c) {
    /* 
        + -> 1
        - -> 1
        * -> 2
        / -> 2
        % -> 2
    */
    switch(c) {
        case '+':
            return 1;

        case '-':
            return 1;

        case '*':
            return 2;

        case '/':
            return 2;

        case '%':
            return 2;

        default:
            // throw "Illegal Operator Detected!";
            cout << "Illegal Operator Detected: " << c << endl;
            return -1;

    }
}

int main() {
    cout << endl;
    int x = 1;

    char inp[] = "(A+B)/(C*D))";

    //Infix i;
    cout << "In main: " << inp  /* + ')' */  << endl << endl;

    // cout << i.infixToPostfix(input + ')', sizeof(input));
/*     for(int i = 0; i < strlen(inp); ++i) {
        cout << inp[i];
    }
 */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: Well, I wanted to experiment a bit with char arrays in C++

Comment: Any reason you ain't using `std::string`?

Comment: well, not any specific  one to say for!

Comment: `std::string` does wrap a char array and it is much more forgiving when doing experiments with it

Comment: well, That I understand.. but I can't figure out why this code is behaving abnormally, and why works fine after removing object declaration line?

Comment: well, if you wish to see the whole code, you can see this:

[Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WVd9fE6KnKMr8uDs8Sj2c9scf4tMsOys)

Comment: Can you share the complete implementation of Infix? (Copy the code in the question)

Comment: yeah, just see the coment above

Comment: The whole 'Infix' implementation and the class, 'Stack' from which it is derived too!

Comment: @ShivamJha I can't open that on mobile

Comment: wait A SEC LET ME SEE

Comment: Stack class: [Stack](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xFvJYMeGJPMrYIHY1QtI-jJlcUa1mmp9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Infix Class: [Infix](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QZfJ4mtWwMPzyAy2o0kc8rODA17rwL7r)

Comment: These two are ".txt" files link of implementations

Comment: You nedd to download them, before you can view them, I guess

Comment: @JVApen I've included implementations in the Edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `operatorArray` as an array of `char` but you are **not** assigning any memory for it! So, when you then call `strcpy(operatorArray, "/*-+%");` in your `Infix` constructor, you are causing **undefined behaviour** by attempting to copy the given string constant to memory that hasn't been assigned - and this appears to be overwriting the `inp[]` array declared in your `main`.

To fix this, I would suggest giving your `operatorArray` member a specific size, which will be large enough to accommodate whatever string you want to copy to it - 8 characters will work in the sample code you've given:

```cpp
class Infix : public Stack {
    string outputString;
    char operatorArray[8]; // Make this member a REAL array of characters.
    //..
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch bro!
I've been trying to find this bug for 2 days now.
So happy that you helped!

But, why the compiler has not warned me about this?

Comment: @ShivamJha It depends on your compiler and on the settings you have used (whether or not all warnings are enabled). In Visual Studio 2019 with the `MSVC` compiler, I get: **warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union**.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `char operatorArray[]` have no memory allocated when your constructor is called. When you use `strcpy`, you write to a place where you don't have permissions in your memory, and therefore on other informations.
To find these kinds of mistakes, I recommend using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: Yeah, same as Adrain
Thanks for you help bruh!

Going to look at your valgrind

Answer (score 0):

`char operatorArray[];` is not allowed in Standard C++.

If you didn't see an error message then I would recommend adjusting compiler settings to follow the standard form of the language,  this would have saved you a lot of time.